# Shiny module saving csv file as HTML

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R shiny app. I want the user to be able to save a table as a csv file.
In my download_module.R file I have

```
# download_module.R

downloadDataUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    downloadButton(ns("downloadData"), "Download Processed Data")
  )
}

downloadDataServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("processed_PCR_data_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        # Ensure that you're explicitly specifying the file extension as .csv
        write.csv(wrangled_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

My server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
function(input, output, session) {

  # Read the uploaded CSV file
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    inFile <- input$file
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  })
  
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')

    })
    
    # reactive expression for data wrangling
    wrangled_data <- reactive({
      req(data())
      df <- data()
      # Perform your data wrangling operations here
      #data wrangling here
      
      return(df)
    })
    
    # Display the table using DataTable in "Calculations" tab
    output$calculations_table <- renderDataTable({
      req(wrangled_data())
      wrangled_data()
    })
    
    

}
```

and UI.R

```
#
#
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

source("download_module.R")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30),
            fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File", accept = c(".csv")),
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot"),
            tabPanel(HTML("Calcs"), value = 1,
              h4(HTML("<b>Table</b>")),
              tags$br(),
              dataTableOutput("calculations_table"),
              # Add this inside your UI, preferably in the "Calculations" tabPanel
              downloadDataUI("downloads_data"),
                                  )
        )
    )
)
```

When the user tries to download the table, it gets saved as HTML rather than .csv. The output$downloadData section works fine when it is is in the server side. How can this be fixed to make the file be a .csv?

Comment: Where is `wrangled_data()` defined? What exactly are the contents of the HTML file that is downloaded? What file name is it given? Are you running in the RStudio browser or are you running your application from an actual web browser?

Comment: Sorry this code has been updated. Running in RStudio. The HTML saves the UI rather than the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `downloadDataServer("downloads_data")` is never referenced in your server function. Therefore, the `downloadHandler()` is never executed. I noticed that the default name for the file was `download.html` (at least on my Linux system), which indicated to me that the module was not working properly.

If you add:

```r
observe({
    downloadDataServer("downloads_data", wrangled_data())
})
```

in your server function it should work with the additional change below.

The `downloadHandler` function doesn't have access to `wrangled_data()` which is why I've passed the reactive call into `downloadDataServer(...)`. The module will need to be adjusted accordingly to accept a data frame, which I have called `df` below.

```r
downloadDataServer <- function(id, df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("processed_PCR_data_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(df, file, row.names = FALSE)
      },
    )
  })
}
```